# Circe: decoding a container type with different possible content types

Tags: json, scala, circe

My goal is to transform JSON into the following model:

```
case class Container(typeId: Int, timestamp: Long, content: Content)

sealed trait Content
case class ContentType1(...) extends Content
case class ContentType2(...) extends Content
case class ContentType3(...) extends Content
```

- There is a container type whose structure always looks the same.
- The `content` of the container is represented by types that look totally different (regarding the amount and type of attributes). However, all content types are known at compile time and implement a sealed trait.
- the `typeId` attribute of the container indicates the content type. E.g. a value of `N` means that `content` is of type `ContentTypeN`and so on.
- The JSON structure looks exactly like you would expect it to do and maps direcly to the Scala types shown above.
- (Btw: I'm open to change the container type to `Container[A <: Content]` if that's a more elegant solution).

What would be a good way to decode that with circe? I guess automatic decoding does not work in this case.

*edit*: the documentation of the json structure describes the content field as `?mixed (object, integer, bool)`, so it can also be a simple `Int` or `Boolean` instead of a case class object. But for now it would be ok to ignore these two types (although it would be nice to have a solution for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use semiauto (with deriveDecoder), [validate](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/Decoder.html#validate(pred:io.circe.HCursor=>Boolean,message:=>String):io.circe.Decoder[A]) and [or](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/Decoder.html#or[AA>:A](d:=>io.circe.Decoder[AA]):io.circe.Decoder[AA]).

```
case class Container[+C](typeId: Int, timestamp: Long, content: C)

sealed trait Content
@JsonCodec case class ContentType1(...) extends Content
@JsonCodec case class ContentType2(...) extends Content

object Content {
  import shapeless._
  import io.circe._
  import io.circe.generic.semiauto._

  def decodeContentWithGuard[T: Decoder](number: Int): Decoder[Content[T]] = {
    deriveDecoder[Content[T]].validate(_.downField("typeId") == Right(number), s"wrong type number, expected $number")
  }

  implicit val contentDecoder: Decoder[Container[Content]] = {
    decodeWithGuard[ContentType1](1) or
    decodeWithGuard[ContentType2](2)
  }
}
```

If you don't want the covariant annotation, you'll have to map and upcast the inner `ContentTypeX` to `Content`.

There's probably also a solution without the generic, but then you can't use semiauto.

Might not compile, didn't test it.